# Iterate sub-directories and zip files with same prefix and remove original files after compression

Tags: directory, zip

I have the current code:

```
for fname in *.*; do
    prefix=${fname%.*}
    [ ! -f "$fname" ] || [ -f "$prefix.zip" ] && continue
    zip "$prefix" "$prefix".*
done
```

This mostly does what I want, but I have to delete the original files. Is there a modification that can be made to remove the original files after compression? If possible, how can I execute this on a directory or its subdirectories?

The current file structure is as follows:

```
-rootDir
|- Dir1
 |- file1.jpg
 |- file1.png
 |- file1.mp3
|- Dir2
 |- file2.jpg
 |- file2.png
 |- file2.mp3
```

I am aiming for the structure below:

```
-rootDir
|- Dir1
 |- file1.zip
|- Dir2
 |- file2.zip
```

As mentioned, the above code works fine when executed in a single directory.

I now have 300 subdirectories, and it would be of great assistance to me if I could obtain a modified version of the above code to execute at the root directory level, as well as tidy up the remaining files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zip` has a `--move` (`-m`) option to ask it to move files into an archive, *i.e.* delete them after they’ve been successfully added to the archive. It is recommended to pair it with the `-T` option to test the archive before actually removing the files:

```bash
zip -mT "$prefix" "$prefix".*
```

To handle multiple directories, you can loop over them:

```bash
for dir in */; do
    (cd "$dir" && for fname in *.*; do
        prefix="${fname%.*}"
        [ ! -f "$fname" ] || [ -f "$prefix.zip" ] && continue
        zip -mT "$prefix" "$prefix".*
    done)
done
```